# PDF reader without any controls

Tags: pdf-viewer

I am looking for a PDF reader, where I can dump the PDFs and send the .exe or the link to the users. When launched, users should be able to read the document, but they should not be able to copy text, save, or save as document, print, and download.

Comment: What's the real reason of this request? Securing PDFs against copying?

Answer (score 3):

I think you should instead lock down the .pdf, i dont know of any (or any reason why someone wanted to make a  "no features" .pdf reader)

in Acrobat you can have different security settings, I know because from time to time i will receive a PDF link i can not edit, save or print